# How can i get text option from AJAX generated select dropdown using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to populate dropdown using AJAX and trying to get the text field of select dropdown along with the value of that selection. I am getting the text but only the preselected text. If i change the selection in second dropdown the text corresponding to the value doesnt change. Here is what i have tried -

```js
     < script type = "text/javascript" >
      function AjaxFunction() {
        var httpxml;
        try {
          // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
          httpxml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
          // Internet Explorer
          try {
            httpxml = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          } catch (e) {
            try {
              httpxml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
              alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
              return false;
            }
          }
        }

        function stateck() {
            if (httpxml.readyState == 4 && httpxml.status == 200) {
              //alert(httpxml.responseText);
              var myarray = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);
              // Remove the options from 2nd dropdown list 
              for (j = document.testform.subcat_id.options.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                document.testform.subcat_id.remove(j);
              }
              for (i = 0; i < myarray.data.length; i++) {
                var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
                optn.text = myarray.data[i].Description;
                optn.value = myarray.data[i].Component_ID;
                document.testform.subcat_id.options.add(optn);
                document.getElementById("des").value = $("#subcat_id option:selected").text(); // here i get the text
              }
            }
          } // end of function stateck
        var url = "production_add_filter.php";
        var cat_id = document.getElementById('cat_id').value;
        url = url + "?cat_id=" + cat_id;
        url = url + "&sid=" + Math.random();
        httpxml.onreadystatechange = stateck;
        //alert(url);
        httpxml.open("GET", url, true);
        httpxml.send(null);
      } < /script>
```

```html
<form name="testform" method='POST' action="production_add_exec.php">
  <label>Select Category :</label>
  <select name=cat_id id="cat_id" onchange=AjaxFunction(); required>
    <option value=''>Select One</option></select>
    <label>Select Component :</label>
    <select name=subcat_id id='subcat_id' required>
      <option value=''>Select One</option>
    </select>
    <input id="des" type=text>//updated text value required here !
    <input type=submit value=submit>
</form>
```

Updated code -

```
for (i=0;i<myarray.data.length;i++)
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = myarray.data[i].Description;
optn.value = myarray.data[i].Component_ID;  
document.testform.subcat_id.options.add(optn);
document.getElementById("des").value = $("#subcat_id option:selected").text();
}
document.getElementById("des").value = $('#subcat_id').change(function() {
 $('#des').val($('#subcat_id option:selected').text());
});

  }
}
```

Comment: Your html is wrong you didn't close first select.

Comment: You should put this line `document.getElementById("des").value = $("#subcat_id option:selected").text();` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add change event to second select:

```
$('#subcat_id').change(function() {
     $('#des').val($('#subcat_id option:selected').text());
});
```

Comment: Just make sure you don't add it in the for loop or on change you will have the function triggered for each added option.

Comment: @OxyDesign alright.. but whenever i select 1st dropdown the selection made in the second dropdown (1st option by default) gets stored as '[object Object]' unless i dont change my selection. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure you have `.text()` after `$('#subcat_id option:selected')` ? Can you add your current code ?

Comment: @OxyDesign please check the updated code in question. thanks

Comment: @Kaus just remove `document.getElementById("des").value = ` in front of `$('#subcat_id').change(`

Comment: I see. Dont use `document.getElementById("des").value = $('#subcat_id').change(function() {
 $('#des').val($('#subcat_id option:selected').text());
});` but only `$('#subcat_id').change(function() {
 $('#des').val($('#subcat_id option:selected').text());
});` otherwise you're assigning the return of the `$` function to the value of the input (and it's an object)

Comment: And this `$('#subcat_id').change(function() { $('#des').val($('#subcat_id option:selected').text()); });` should be out of the `AjaxFunction` otherwise every time you call `AjaxFunction` you will add a new listener on your select.